# How to solve a sync problme with several fetch?

Tags: javascript, async-await, synchronization, fetch

I am doing several fecth.

```
  let var1 = []
  let var2 = []

  await dateArray?.map((day) => {
    for (const o of myFirstList) {
      for (const d of mySecondList) {
        const resp = fetch(url-with-params)
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((data) => {
            const f = manipulateResponse(data)

            logger.info('1: manipulated data')

            var1.push(f.data1)
            var2.push(f.data2)
          })
      }
    }
  })

  logger.info('2: return response')
  let response = {
    var1,
    var2,
  }

  return response
```

The problem is the log `return response` is being called first then `manipulated data`.

How can I assure to run all fetch's before the function return the complete result?

PS: I have done with `then()` and `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript and the fact that fetch returns a Promise. One way is to use `Promise.all` to wait for all the promises generated by the fetch requests to be resolved.

Example:

```js
let var1 = [];
let var2 = [];

// Create an array to store all the fetch promises
const fetchPromises = [];

await dateArray?.map((day) => {
  for (const o of myFirstList) {
    for (const d of mySecondList) {
      const respPromise = fetch(url-with-params)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const f = manipulateResponse(data);

          logger.info('1: manipulated data');

          var1.push(f.data1);
          var2.push(f.data2);
        });

      // Add the promise to the array
      fetchPromises.push(respPromise);
    }
  }
});

// Use Promise.all to wait for all fetch promises to resolve
await Promise.all(fetchPromises);

logger.info('2: return response');
let response = {
  var1,
  var2,
};

return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure all the fetch operations complete before returning the response, use `Promise.all` with `await` on an array of fetch promises. This will wait for all fetch operations to finish before proceeding