# Random order API list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a Pokédex using HTML,CSS and Javascript. I had to generate the Pokemon list with (https://pokeapi.co/). Meanwhile, when displaying the list I found out that it's not in order and when I refresh the page it switches the order again. Can someone please let me know what's the issue...

Here's my code below

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const pokemonList = document.querySelector('.pokemon-list');
    const pokemonDetails = document.querySelector('.pokemon-details');

    function fetchPokemonDetails(id) {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => displayPokemonDetails(data));
    }

    function displayPokemonDetails(pokemon) {
        pokemonDetails.innerHTML = `
            <h2>${pokemon.name}</h2>
            <img src="${pokemon.sprites.front_default}" alt="${pokemon.name}">
            <p>Height: ${pokemon.height} dm</p>
            <p>Weight: ${pokemon.weight} hg</p>
        `;

        pokemonDetails.style.display = 'block';
    }


    function displayPokemon(pokemon) {
        const pokemonCard = document.createElement('div');
        pokemonCard.classList.add('pokemon');
        pokemonCard.dataset.id = pokemon.id;

        pokemonCard.innerHTML = `
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png" alt="${pokemon.name}">
            <p>${pokemon.name}</p>
        `;

        pokemonCard.addEventListener('click', function () {
            const id = this.dataset.id;
            fetchPokemonDetails(id);
        });

        pokemonList.appendChild(pokemonCard);
    }


    for (let i = 1; i <= 1016; i++) {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => displayPokemon(data));
    }

    pokemonList.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

});
```

Here's a preview of the list:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NsYE.jpg)

Here's a preview after refreshing:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e06b2.jpg)

Comment: You shouldn't get 1016 pokemons by a for loop, but use the api route that returns all pokemons

Comment: The fetch calls are asynchronous. The pokemon are listed in the order the fetch calls resolve.

Comment: It sounds like you're just using the wrong API endpoint for the initial load of the page?  It seems kind of silly to fetch the details for every pokemon, and attach a click handler to each of them to fetch their details (which you've already fetched and already have).  Presumably that API has a way to get the *list* of Pokemon, and what's what you should be using when loading the page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a sync problme with several fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432258/how-to-solve-a-sync-problme-with-several-fetch)

Comment: as suggested, rather than request them one at a time, https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=5000 returns all of them (needs a limit on there, as defaults to 10 at a time otherwise)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because every `fetch` function's response time is different.

For example, for `1` , `2` you call `fetch(http/.../1)` before `fetch(http/.../2)`. right?

But server can response `fetch(http/.../1)` after `fetch(http/.../2)` because of so many reasons such as network problems.

To solve this problem, you have to use `async` and `await`.

if you use this, `fetch(http/.../2)` is called after `fetch(http/.../1)`'s response is come.

I add code below.

-javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {

...

for (let i = 1; i <= 1016; i++) {
  await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      displayPokemon(data);
    });
}

//don't need to sort because everytime you reload page, the result is same.
```

I think it'll works and can help you enoughly.

Good luck.

Comment: Nitpick: _"you have to use `async` and `await`."_ That's not correct. There are multiple different options. `async`/`await` is one possible option, but not the only option.

Comment: what are multiple different options? for example?

Comment: There was a time before `async`/`await`. Do you really think it was impossible to solve this problem before `async`/`await`? One option is `Promise.all`. There was even a time before promises in JavaScript and a solution without promises.

Comment: Do you mean `async` and `await` are non-useful?

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine! Like @jabaa said there might be other options to do it but your way seems to be more simpler.

Comment: I say your statement is not correct. It's not the only option.

Comment: I don't say it's only way. So, @jabba, you mean I have to explain all the answers?

Comment: _"To solve this problem, you have to use..."_ means, it's the only way. The statement is wrong if different solutions exist.

Comment: It means 'I think it's the best one to...'. I didn't say 'you must....'

Comment: _"You have to..."_ and _" You must..."_ means the same. If you mean, it's the best way in your opinion, write it.

Comment: ok, ok, I'm sorry, really really and really sorry. Are you happy now?

Comment: No, it's still wrong in your answer

Comment: Guys it's fine no one is at fault over here, just a misunderstanding that's all. Thanks for helping both of you!

Comment: @KAIJUU The goal of Stack Overflow is to collect questions and answers to help future users with similar questions. It shouldn't be a problem to edit the answer and fix the wrong statement. It's not correct that _"you have to"_ use `async`/`await`.

Comment: The change suggested here may logically achieve the desired result, but it's worth noting for future readers that it does so in a fantastically inefficient way (because the original code was so inefficient).  It's still hard-coding 1016 records, which could change.  It's fetching every record every time, whether the users wants those details or not.  No change was made to the click event listener, which seems to just unnecessarily re-fetch the same data again.  Etc.  Etc.  The OP really should refer back to the API documentation to find a single (or paged) request that gets a list of records.